# How to store calculated value on right store in the left calculated string

Tags: python, string, nested-loops

I know programming languages don't allow calculations on left side and I can't figure out how to store information otherwise.

```py
myboxes = 'C 0 0 19 42 0\nN 23 8 40 26 0\nI 43 9 46 25 0\nC 49 9 68 27 0\n/ 71 8 81 28 0\nN 84 11 100 30 0\nT 103 13 113 31 0\nN 116 13 132 32 0\n/ 136 12 146 33 0\nP 149 15 161 33 0\na 164 16 181 30 0\ns 183 16 192 31 0\ns 194 16 202 31 0\np 205 7 222 32 0\no 224 18 240 32 0\nr 242 18 249 33 0\nt 251 19 256 38 0\n'
```

myboxes is a string and I have this code to store some information

```py
r[3] = 'CNIC/'
temp = []
for i, b in enumerate(myboxes.splitlines()):
    temp.append(b.split(' '))
    print(b.split(' '))
    print(r[3]+"_"+str(b[0])+'-'+str(i))
    if temp[i][0] == '/':
        break
```

output of this will be

```py
['C', '0', '0', '19', '42', '0']
CNIC_C-0
['N', '23', '8', '40', '26', '0']
CNIC_N-1
['I', '43', '9', '46', '25', '0']
CNIC_I-2
['C', '49', '9', '68', '27', '0']
CNIC_C-3
['/', '71', '8', '81', '28', '0']
CNIC_/-4
```

These are letters found by tesseract and their coordinates as 'x', 'y', 'width' and 'height'. I want to obtain coordinates for first and last 'C' however if i do

```py
for i, c in enumerate(temp):
    print(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4])
    char, x,y, width, height = c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]
```

then I get coordinates for last character `['/', '71', '8', '81', '28', '0']` , but I need coordinates for first 'C' and last 'C' (first and last characters in 'CNIC'. If it were possible to calculate on left side of equation then it would be possible to store this information somehow, but what do I do now?

I tried code above (and below).

```py
for i, c in enumerate(temp):
    print(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4])
    char, x,y, width, height = c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]
```

Comment: What is `r` referring to?

Comment: That was a list of coordinates and name of the field that I gave to particular coordinates.

Comment: You have to provide a reproducible example. With `r`, we can't reproduce what you are doing. Please provide a self-contained piece of code.

Comment: r = ['Name', 'ID', 'Phone', 'CNIC/']

Answer (score 0):

programming languages, as stated above in question, do not perform calculations on left side of equation, that is reserved for variables which are set on right side.

For this question, however, a possible solution would be to add the outputs in a list and then append already created list and then retrieve required information later.

```py
outputs = list()
for i, c in enumerate(temp):
```

```
outputs.append([c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]])
```

Comment: Did you answer your own question?